# Need to print 10 different question booklets(aka Forms) but not able to print 9 of them as only the last one gets created and printed

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

```
import random

capitals = {'Alabama': 'Montgomery', 'Alaska': 'Juneau', 'Arizona': 'Phoenix',
'Arkansas': 'Little Rock', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Colorado': 'Denver',
'Connecticut': 'Hartford', 'Delaware': 'Dover', 'Florida': 'Tallahassee',
'Georgia': 'Atlanta', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu', 'Idaho': 'Boise', 'Illinois':
'Springfield', 'Indiana': 'Indianapolis', 'Iowa': 'Des Moines', 'Kansas':
'Topeka', 'Kentucky': 'Frankfort', 'Louisiana': 'Baton Rouge', 'Maine':
'Augusta', 'Maryland': 'Annapolis', 'Massachusetts': 'Boston', 'Michigan':
'Lansing', 'Minnesota': 'Saint Paul', 'Mississippi': 'Jackson', 'Missouri':
'Jefferson City', 'Montana': 'Helena', 'Nebraska': 'Lincoln', 'Nevada':
'Carson City', 'New Hampshire': 'Concord', 'New Jersey': 'Trenton', 'NewMexico': 'Santa Fe', 'New York': 'Albany', 'North Carolina': 'Raleigh',
'North Dakota': 'Bismarck', 'Ohio': 'Columbus', 'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City',
'Oregon': 'Salem', 'Pennsylvania': 'Harrisburg', 'Rhode Island': 'Providence',
'South Carolina': 'Columbia'}


for quizNum in range(10):
            quizFile = open('capitalsquiz%s.txt' % (quizNum + 1), 'w')
            answerKeyFile = open('capitalsquiz_answers%s.txt' % (quizNum + 1), 'w')

            quizFile.write('Name:\n\nDate:\n\nPeriod:\n\n')
            quizFile.write((' ' * 20) + 'State Capitals Quiz (Form %s)' % (quizNum + 1))
            quizFile.write('\n\n')

            states = list(capitals.keys())
            random.shuffle(states)

for questionNum in range(40):
            correctAnswer = capitals[states[questionNum]]
            wrongAnswers = list(capitals.values())
            del wrongAnswers[wrongAnswers.index(correctAnswer)]
            wrongAnswers = random.sample(wrongAnswers, 3)
            answerOptions = wrongAnswers + [correctAnswer]
            random.shuffle(answerOptions)

            quizFile.write('%s. What is the capital of %s?\n' % (questionNum + 1,states[questionNum]))
            for i in range(4):
                quizFile.write('   %s. %s\n' % ('ABCD'[i], answerOptions[i]))
            quizFile.write('\n')
            answerKeyFile.write('%s. %s\n' % (questionNum + 1, 'ABCD'[answerOptions.index(correctAnswer)]))
quizFile.close()
answerKeyFile.close()
```

***The remaining 9 booklets are created as .txt files but are blank. Where am I going wrong ?***

Questions involve the capital cities of U.S.A

Expected file form is :
Name:
Date:
Period:
State Capitals Quiz (Form 1)

1. What is the capital of West Virginia?
   A. Hartford
   B. Santa Fe
   C. Harrisburg
   D. Charleston
2. What is the capital of Colorado?
   A. Raleigh
   B. Harrisburg
   C. Denver
   D. Lincoln

3......

and so on . Like that for all the other files(remaining 9 .txt files which get created) questions would have to be printed.But they just turn out to be blank.

***Each question booklets has the same questions but are in different order(to prevent cheating)***

Answer (score 0):

You questions loop is outside of the file loop. This is causing all of the files to be opened before any questions are written, then the last opened file is what gets the questions

I can post the fix later if needed, just on my phone right now.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you tell me which loop you are talking about

Comment: Basically indent everything under random.shuffle(states) until 'for questionNum____', quizfile.close(), and answerkeyfile.close() are even with random.shuffle(states)

Comment: No problem  Just make sure to accept the answer so the question is closed out